# Server side generated javascript array throws unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, syntax

This Is how I generate it in back end:

```
$scr = '';
    forech(){
        $scr .= '['.$key.',"'.$address.'",'.$lat.','.$lng.',"'.$post_title.'","'.$post_image.'","'.$post_url.'","'.$default_price.'","'.$excerpt.' "],';
    }
```

And this Is where I output it:

```
var events = [<?php echo $scr; ?>];
```

But I get this error in the firebug console (Content dependent, because with other content didnt happen using same code:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal


ent/encantadora-casa-moditerranea-con-vistas-al-mar/","118","
```

(by viewing source-code I can see a line break after that code)

Any way to escape somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to roll your own serialization to JavaScript when you have [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode). Just dump the whole output into your page, and stop worrying about escaping.

```
var events = <?php echo json_encode($my_array_thing); ?>;
```

Comment: This is the only *safe* solution.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel thanks for the edit. I don't _actually_ know (much less write!) PHP `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put all the variables you need into an array like this:

```
$a = array(1,true,null,"x",0.2, array("some","deven deeper","nested values"));
```

and then use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
var events = <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I always advise to have a cleaner approach.

```
<script type="application/json" id="yourArray">
<?php echo json_encode($yourArray); ?>
</script>

...

<script>

  var events = $.parseJSON($('#yourArray').text());

</script>
```

This way your javascript code is totally decoupled from PHP.

Comment: To really decouple it, though, you'd use jsonp, no?

Comment: @jameslafferty JSONP is just to circumvent cross domain issues.

Comment: Yuck. Why would you read the contents of a `<script>` tag (as text, no less) just to parseJSON, when you could assign the output to a variable and let the browser worry about the parsing? JSON is already a valid subset of JavaScript.

Comment: @MattBall because if you move your js to an external file/a CDN [which would be a good practice], you don't have to worry about where does data come from. The parsing part is just to be prevent XSS - in case you have total control of your data source, you can skip it of course.

Comment: @moonwave If I provide a service at /api/path/to/greatness and call it with ?callback=awesomefunc, then use that as the src element of script tag, I've kept away from the ugliness of embedding json in my page and more effectively decoupled my client and server apps, no?

Comment: @jameslafferty yes, but in that case you don't need JSNOP at all, a plain `$.get` would do - as long as html and api are served from same domain.

Comment: @moonwave99 Not sure you're following... I'm saying ```<script src="/api/path/to/greatness?callback=awesomefunc"></script>``` with /api/path/to/greatness doing something like ```echo "{$_GET['callback']}(" . json_encode($data) . ");";```. That's still jsonp, but it's just there to 1. improve performance and 2. better seperate front and back end code.